# How do I get the context menu in the node editor/3d editor (and more) if I preffer to use Right Click Selection?

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

I know that people with left click selection bring up that menu with right click, however, with right click selection I simply can't find a way to bring up the context menu, and I don't want to change to left click selection.

Comment: I was a fan of the Right-Click select, but in 2.80 there is no good reason not to switch to the Left-Click. In Right-Click mode, the Left-Click is just used to move the cursor, which you almost never set by hand with the mouse, and is basically useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default key for the context menu is "w". I use it since I also use right-click select.